# One formula for Neural Network Design

Tags: neural-network

There is a famous formula (used e.g. in many Metatrader's MQL bound FANN derivatives)

n, n, n/2+1, 1

describing 4-layer (two hidden layers) network. Here n is the number of neurons in an input layer, the first hidden layer has n, the second n/2+1, and the output is a boolean.

Does anybody know the origin of this formula?

Comment: I think you should ask the developers directly.

Answer (score 0):

A 3-layer MLP can approximate continuous functions.

A 4-layer MLP is even more general, and can deal with discontinuous functions (think step or Heaviside functions).

There's no particular rhyme or reason for the topology, but having four layers enhances the applicability.